# How can I temporary or permanently change the math formula colors in Wikipedia pages?

Tags: colors, formula, wikipedia, math-functions

The question in the caption is sufficiently verbose imho.

The background for it is my dark browser theme (I hate bright whites) in which black text (e.g. the Wikipedia-math-formulas) are not readable.

Further info: the said formulas are svg-files but when I understood correctly from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Color you can change them to white accordingly.

I just don't know enough html and css to make this changes in my browser neither temporary nor permanently, of which the latter is preferable, obviously. So if you know sufficient html and css, I kindly ask you, if you can help me out with this :-).

PS: If this may an impossible problem, please let me know too, and why so.

Thank y'all in advance. You guys and gals rule.

Comment: Hey, have you tried pasting this in your wiki page and see how it comes? For eg: \color{Blue}{x^2}+\color{Orange}{2x}-\color{LimeGreen}{1} OR just {color{Blue}Steffan W.}

Comment: Hi. Where do you mean that I should paste these lines into - the url, randomly into the html source code? Both didn't work.

Comment: At the end or may be at the start of you wiki page..so that you can check how it is appearing,.in case not..try updating your question with the screenshot as well

Comment: Try this {{ font color | green | Steffen W. }}

Comment: @BhawnaJain I tried to get this piece of code somewhere in the html code of the Wiki-page, but without effect.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki uses LateX to write documents that include complex math expressions or non-Latin scripts, such as Arabic, Sanskrit and Chinese.

You can edit your source code from here:

1. Log in your Wiki account.
2. Go to the page which you want to change.
3. Go to View **Edit source** tab.
4. Using ctrl+F, type the text which you are searching for or may be add test content in the end of your page. Do the required change.
5. Click on **Show preview**. 
   After checking the preview, you can publish your changes.
   [image]

[image]

Try this, you were not adding `<math>` tag :

```
<math>
{\color{Blue}x^2}+{\color{Orange}2x}-{\color{LimeGreen}1}
</math>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure where to put this piece of code, since I'm a html newbie. When I open the developers options in Chrome I can see the the html code under the tab "Elements". Is it supposed to go somewhere there? Where exactly? Thanks for explaining.